# How do I use Python to auto generate a simple powerpoint example?

Tags: python, powerpoint, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to reproduce the result of the example file provided by Prof. Zhao using Enthought Canopy:

http://www.shengdongzhao.com/shen_blog/how-to-automatically-create-powerpoint-slides-using-python/

I seem to be having the same problem that others are having (and seem to still be having) which you can see in the comments below the linked blog post. I realize prof. Zhao mentions that the error could be due to the environment not being set correctly. I thought it might have something to do with environment variables not being pointed to correctly. I tried the the first answer at the following but it seems like it prevents canopy from even opening (doing something wrong I am)

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7/4855685#4855685)

So what I'm left doing is: I open his scripts in Canopy and then I run MSO.py and then MSPPT.py and then MSPPTUtil.py. Then, when I run CreateSlideExamples.py (with photo.JPG's directory updated) I only get a single power-point slide with the table

[image]

The console is littered with the following list of errors:

```
%run C:/Users/dirkh_000/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_MSPPT.zip/MSO.py

%run "C:/Users/dirkh_000/Documents/Python scripts/Auto pp example/MSPPT.py"

%run "C:/Users/dirkh_000/Documents/Python scripts/Auto pp example/MSPPTUtil.py"

%run "C:/Users/dirkh_000/Documents/Python scripts/Auto pp example/CreateSlideExamples.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\dirkh_000\Documents\Python scripts\Auto pp example\CreateSlideExamples.py in <module>()
     40 
     41 # step 3: show the slide
---> 42 presentation.create_show()
     43 
     44 # Now you can save the slide somewhere

C:\Users\dirkh_000\Documents\Python scripts\Auto pp example\MSPPTUtil.pyc in create_show(self, visible)
     45                         if visible:
     46                                 slide.select() #bring slide to front
---> 47                         slide.format_slide()
     48         def save_as(self, file_name):
     49                 self.presentation.SaveAs(file_name)

C:\Users\dirkh_000\Documents\Python scripts\Auto pp example\MSPPTUtil.pyc in format_slide(self)
     64                 self.slide.Select()
     65         def format_slide(self):
---> 66                 self.format_content()
     67                 self.format_title()
     68         def format_title(self):

C:\Users\dirkh_000\Documents\Python scripts\Auto pp example\MSPPTUtil.pyc in format_content(self)
    252                 if self.title:
    253                         #add title
--> 254                         title_range = slide.Shapes[0].TextFrame.TextRange
    255                         title_range.Text = self.title
    256                         title_range.Font.Bold = True

C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
    463                 args=self._prop_map_get_.get(attr)
    464                 if args is None:
--> 465                         raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
    466                 return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
    467 

AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library.Shapes instance at 0x164276808>' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm running windows 8.1, powerpoint 2013.

Comment: Try www.pptxbuilder.com